# "1 Physical GPUs, 0 Logical GPU " when i train the model the gpu is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, gpu

ubntu version 18.04
nvidia Smia 440.1.0
cuda 10.2
GTx 960
tensorboard  2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.7.0
tensorflow-estimator  2.3.0
tensorflow-gpu   2.3.0

My gpu is not working or you can say its installed but when  i run the model it's not allocating to the gpu
here the image

Answer (score 0):

run this code to see if tensorflow is detecting your gpu. If number of gpus is listed as 0 then it is not detecting it. You need to have  Cuda 10.1 on your systen and cuDNN v7.6.5. In that case  if you are using Anaconda open the conda prompt and run conda install cuDNN=7.6.5. You may also have to install CUDA Toolkit 10.1. If you installed tensorflow with pip then you have to download and install CUDA Toolkit 10.1 and modify your environment variables etc. I found the easiest solution is to install tensorflow using Conda because it installs both the toolkit and cudnn automatically. IF you are using Anaconda then open the conda prompt and run conda fistall --upgrade tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print(tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
!python --version
```

Comment: I am doing my project on ubnutu 18.04, and after seeing your comment , i tried so many times to install cuda toolkit 10.1 but when i installed nvidia driver , the cuda version shows me 11 as i run nvidia smi.  So followed some other tutorial and some how when i run the command nvcc version it shows 10.1 , i am wondering how  to set the environment variable , is it possible to install two cuda tool kit and can set one of them? If it then how we cam check that we have done it